# Verilog: simulation gives errors but runs fine on FPGA

Tags: verilog, simulation, verilator

I'm trying to familiarize myself with (sub)modules in verilog and I am running into errors I cannot explain. I have these two files:

*top.v*:

```
parameter CLOCK_FREQUENCY = 24'd12_000_000;
parameter TRANSMISSION_LENGTH = 32;

`include "serialtx.v"

module top(
        input clk,
        output txd
    );
    
    reg wr;
    reg [TRANSMISSION_LENGTH - 1:0] data;
    reg busy;
    
    initial wr = 1'b0;
    initial data = 0;
    
    serialtx tx(
        .i_clk(clk),
        .i_wr(wr),
        .i_data(data),
        .o_txd(txd),
        .o_busy(busy)
    );
    
endmodule
```

*serialtx.v*:

```
module serialtx(
        input i_clk,
        input i_wr,
        input [TRANSMISSION_LENGTH - 1:0] i_data,
        output wire o_txd,
        output wire o_busy
    );
    
    initial o_busy = 1'b0;
    initial o_txd = 1'b1;
    
    always @(posedge i_clk)
    begin
        if (i_wr && !o_busy) begin
            o_busy <= 1'b1;
            o_txd <= 1'b0;
        end
    end
    
endmodule
```

To upload them to my ECP5 I use the following command flow:

```
yosys -p "synth_ecp5 -json top.json" top.v
nextpnr-ecp5 --json top.json --textcfg top_out.config --um5g-85k --package CABGA381 --lpf ecp5evn.lpf
ecppack --svf top.svf top_out.config top.bit
sudo --preserve-env=PATH env openocd -f ./ecp5.cfg -c "transport select jtag; init; svf top.svf; exit"
```

It uploads and works fine (there is a led connected to txd and it turns on/off accordingly to the `initial o_txd = 1'bx` statement in *serialtx.v* where x can be 1 or 0).

However, when I try to simulate the verilog code I get some errors. I cannot explain these errors since the error messages are chinese to me and the actual implementation works. This is the command I use:

```
verilator -Wall --trace -cc top.v
```

And this is the generated error log:

```
%Error-PROCASSWIRE: serialtx.v:9:10: Procedural assignment to wire, perhaps intended var (IEEE 1800-2017 6.5): 'o_busy'
                                   : ... In instance top.tx
    9 |  initial o_busy = 1'b0;
      |          ^~~~~~
                    top.v:2:35: ... note: In file included from top.v
                    ... For error description see https://verilator.org/warn/PROCASSWIRE?v=4.215
%Error-PROCASSWIRE: serialtx.v:10:10: Procedural assignment to wire, perhaps intended var (IEEE 1800-2017 6.5): 'o_txd'
                                    : ... In instance top.tx
   10 |  initial o_txd = 1'b1;
      |          ^~~~~
                    top.v:2:35: ... note: In file included from top.v
%Error-PROCASSWIRE: serialtx.v:15:4: Procedural assignment to wire, perhaps intended var (IEEE 1800-2017 6.5): 'o_busy'
                                   : ... In instance top.tx
   15 |    o_busy <= 1'b1;
      |    ^~~~~~
                    top.v:2:35: ... note: In file included from top.v
%Error-PROCASSWIRE: serialtx.v:16:4: Procedural assignment to wire, perhaps intended var (IEEE 1800-2017 6.5): 'o_txd'
                                   : ... In instance top.tx
   16 |    o_txd <= 1'b0;
      |    ^~~~~
                    top.v:2:35: ... note: In file included from top.v
%Warning-UNUSED: top.v:13:6: Signal is not used: 'busy'
                           : ... In instance top
   13 |  reg busy;
      |      ^~~~
                 ... Use "/* verilator lint_off UNUSED */" and lint_on around source to disable this message.
%Warning-UNUSED: top.v:1:11: Parameter is not used: 'CLOCK_FREQUENCY'
                           : ... In instance top
    1 | parameter CLOCK_FREQUENCY = 24'd12_000_000;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%Warning-UNUSED: serialtx.v:4:37: Signal is not used: 'i_data'
                                : ... In instance top.tx
    4 |   input [TRANSMISSION_LENGTH - 1:0] i_data,
      |                                     ^~~~~~
                 top.v:2:35: ... note: In file included from top.v
%Error: Exiting due to 4 error(s), 3 warning(s)
        ... See the manual at https://verilator.org/verilator_doc.html for more assistance.
```

[EDIT]
As I understand it, a procedural assignment is an update of the value of a register. Also, outputs are by default defined as wires and not as registers. So, it makes sense that the simulation throws an error. But how could this hardware ever run in the implementation then?

Answer (score 1):

Signals of type `wire` cannot be written procedurally (e.g., in `always` and `initial` blocks). Your synthesis tool should be throwing an error here (like the simulator does), presumably it just treats the signals as `reg`.

To solve this, change your output ports from wire to reg, like so:

```
output reg o_txd,
output reg o_busy
```

Comment: Thanks, after I posted I figured the same about procedural assignments and wires. But it confuses me why the implementation would work. I guess the output type is automatically detected as a reg.

Comment: The distinction between reg and wire in Verilog is very confusing. (And arguably completely unnecessary, VHDL has `signal` for both uses.) It's not too surprising that a synthesis tool doesn't care if you use one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for explaining

Comment: I have a question about the same code. It seems that the submodule (serialtx) does not set txd, in contrast to what I tested earlier. Putting `intial txd = 0` in *top.v* turns the led off, but putting `initial o_txd = 0` or `initial o_txd = 1` in *serialtx.v* seems to have no effect at all. Can you comment on this? Btw, I changed the output type of txd/o_txd to reg, but the output type also seems to have no effect at all.

Comment: One question I would ask is if you need to give `yosys` (which is a tool I'm not familiar with) serialtx.v on the command line, in addition to top.v. It could be that the synthesis tool is "black-boxing" your serialtx-module.

Comment: Sorry, this is about the implementation. In the simulation it runs fine. I found that if I move the contents of *serialtx.v* inside *top.v* it works as expected. So, apparently yosys is not including files in its synthesis. I looked at another multi-file project but my command flow is exactly the same (since I copied it from that project).